# How can I pick pairs from permutations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Sorry, the title does not do a good job describing this. Here's the full description:

I have items $A, B, C$. I'd like to pick two of them (ex: $CA$, or $BC$, or $AB$) - a pair. I'd like to pick a pair from a set that includes all permutations of pairs, where order matters, with sufficient repetition that results in a ratio of A_w:B_w:C_w (ex: 1:1:2).

For example, a set of permutations that results in $1:1:2$ would be:

```
AC
BC
```

($A$ is there once; $B$ once; $C$ twice)

But I could also do `AC CB`, `CA BC`, or `CA CB`, since order matters.

Each of those is a permutation of pairs that results in my ratio, and the 4 of them together is the set of permutations of pairs mentioned above.

With my set of permutations, I'd like to pick one: for example, `CA BC`. Then I'd like to pick one of the pairs: for example, `BC`.

I *think* in this example above, I ultimately end up with a 100% chance to pick a pair that includes `C`, and a 50% chance to pick a pair that includes `A` or `B`.

But, how do I generalise that? Given some `A, B, C, ..., n` and weights `A_w, B_w, C_w, ..., n_w`, where I want to pick pairs, how can I determine the chance of picking a pair that includes some `n`?

I think this requires some probability modeling, but it's a bit above me.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which permutation you have. All of them must have precisely $n_w$ pairs including $n$ out of the total $(A_w + B_w + \cdots) / 2$ pairs to get the required ratio. Therefore the probability of picking a pair including $n$ is always $$2n_w / (A_w + B_w + \cdots).$$

In your example $2C_w / (A_w + B_w + C_w) = 2 \cdot 2 / (1 + 1 + 2) = 4 / 4 = 100\%$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow: shouldn't the probability of picking a pair including C be 100%? Looking above at the four permutations that generate the ratio, every pair includes C.

Comment: My bad, the number of pairs is the sum of the weights divided by 2.